# WPF DataGrid binding with ObservableCollection using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I've got an issues with my MVVM/WPF code which I just cannot fix regardless of how many articles/questions I read.

Basically I am querying a database using Dapper and have the following setup:

1. Customer class is an entity class which mirrors my DB table (Only has name property in it at the moment for testing)
2. CustomerDataAccess class which has a method of "GetCustomers" and puts it into an ObservableCollection
3. AppSession which is my ViewModel
4. My XAML

So what I want to happen is when I click the button "Click" it runs the xaml.cs to run the AppSessions - CDA.getCustomers() to assign to the collection and then bind the collection the XAML.

Without using the button my data processes no problem, but when I try to implement my button it just never maps, can anyone help please?

**Customer Data Access**

```
public class CustomerDataAccess : BaseNotificationClass
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Customer> GetCustomers()
        {
            string sql = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM CUSTOMERS";
            Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();

            using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnectionHelper.ConnectionStringRetrieve("CSharpTesting")))
            {
                var output = connection.Query<Customer>(sql).ToList();
                Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>(output);
                return Customers;
            }
        }
    }
```

**AppSession class**

```
public class AppSession : BaseNotificationClass
    {
        public CustomerDataAccess cda { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Customer> customerList { get; set; }
        public AppSession()
        {
            cda = new CustomerDataAccess();
            //This brings me the right data back
            //cda.Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
            //cda.Customers = cda.GetCustomers();
        }

        public void ListCustomers()
        {
            cda.Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
            cda.Customers = cda.GetCustomers();
        }
    }
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private AppSession _appSession;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _appSession = new AppSession();

            DataContext = _appSession;
        }

        private void OnClick_GetCustomers(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _appSession.ListCustomers();
            //This was just me testing it was clicking
            searchButton.Content = "Clicked";
        }
    }
```

**DataGrid bindings**

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
                  Height="Auto"
                  Width="Auto"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  AlternationCount="3"
                  AlternatingRowBackground="AliceBlue"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding cda.Customers}">

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Office Phone" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Email Address" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Post Code" Width="*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Where is the click event handler being wired up in the XAML? I don't see that it's bound to any control here.

Comment: You need to raise propertychanged from the setter of your collection

Comment: And. Always provide an empty observablecollection for such a property. If you ever set datacontext to a viewmodel has a null observablecollection then the property will be ignored even if you later set it and raise propertychanged.

Comment: It is pointless to assign a new ObservableCollection to cda.Customers directly before assigning the return value of the GetCustomers method. Besides that, the setter of the Customers property must fire a change notification, i.e. the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.